# How to filter two or more columns using "dynamic search" in TextBoxes

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for answer, how to filter two columns at the same time. I have two TextBoxes which filter column A and column B separetly. Its working only when I type in one of them. Is it possible to use two criteria from two textboxes?

WHAT IM LOOKING FOR

[image]

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Else
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox1.Value & "*"
End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
If Len(TextBox2.Value) = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Else
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox2.Value & "*"
End If
End Sub
```

Any help? What commands I need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example of how to filter using two textboxes on a worksheet.

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B8")
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=TextBox1.Value
    .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=TextBox2.Value
End With
```

Comment: Sorry, im trying to implement your idea, but no luck. Could you give me any more hint? Maybe I wasn't accurate enough. Im trying to search specific value from column A search records using column B and vise versa.

Comment: @Taerom if you are trying to do two separate filters than you need to implement two different filters. I suggest using different buttons to implement different filters based on the textbox values.

Comment: Its not like that. Im trying to do two filters with input from two textboxes, which one of them use search records from another one. Its on the example pic in my first post :). First I typed "1" in textbox1 and got 3 results, then I typed "AZ" in textbox2 and from previous 3 result remained 2 results.

Comment: @Taerom that is exactly what this `basic` code does. If you step through the code the first filter for "1" you will see 3 results, the "AZ" in the second textbox will narrow the first filter to only 2 results. You must change the range in this code to the range you want to filter e.g. "A3:B10".

Comment: I tried again and its working. My problem was I implemented this code only in one of the textboxes. In this case, order in which you enter the data in textboxes is important. If the code is in tb1 you first enter in tb2, then tb1. Second problem was that, this filter is working only when both textboxes are filled. I change my code with your help and its working like I want. Thank you GMalc

Answer (score 0):

I know, this code is probably not optimized, but its work like I want.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 And Len(TextBox2.Value) = 0 Then
 ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
ElseIf Len(TextBox2.Value) = 0 Then
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A10").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=TextBox1.Value
Else
  If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If

With ActiveSheet.Range("A3:B10")
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=TextBox1.Value
    .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=TextBox2.Value
End With
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 And Len(TextBox2.Value) = 0 Then
 ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
ElseIf Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
    ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B10").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=TextBox2.Value
Else
  If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End If

With ActiveSheet.Range("A3:B10")
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=TextBox1.Value
    .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=TextBox2.Value
End With
End If
```

End Sub